# How can I find which file system hooks are installed on a windows XP pro machine?

Tags: windows-xp, hook, filesystems

I've a suspect that a program I installed (spideroak) didn't completely removed itself on uninstall. How can I check if there are still file system hooks installed?

#### EDIT:

Probably spideroak wasn't the problem. For some reasons git-cheetah shell extension got enabled on my PC and was interferring with stderr (I've GIT but it's not even in the path... I've a special batch file to add it that I use when working with GIT repos).

Comment: Install spideroak again, then use Revo uninstaller to completely uninstall the program....http://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902) and [ShellExView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html) are the standard tools to get rid of hooks that are left behind.

Watch out what you disable though...

Comment: Thanks. ShellExView did show what was the problematic extension (git-cheetah)... I don't know however if this was the result of installing spireoak as I found no reference about it on their forums

Answer (score 0):

It may be worth doing what Moab said in the comments. However, if you truly do want to view system hooks, you can do this with [InjectedDLL](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/injected_dll.html).